# how can I make this run multiple times using do-while loop?

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that will scan the character I entered and will end only if the character inputted is a vowel or if the number of inputted characters has already reached 5

- when I executed the code it only run once, and even if I inputted a vowel it does not terminate/end.
- I tried adding c++ but it did not change anything
- I feel like something is missing but I can't figure it out.
- I've also tried watching tutorials about do-while loop.

here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char c;

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    
    do {
        printf("%c",c);

    } while (c == 'a' && c == 'e' && c == 'i' && c == 'o' && 'u' && c == 'A' && c == 'E' && c == 'I' && c == 'O' && 'U' && c == 5);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code only reads one character.

Comment: Putting the `scanf` into the loop would be a good start. Then check the condition - that says that the loop continues whilst all the sub conditions are true. How can `c` be all those letters at the same time as that is what `&&` means?

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a count and check if count < 5 and it is not any vowel

```
string ch ;
        cin >> ch ;
        int count = 1 ;
        while(count < 5 && ch != "A" && ch!= "E" && ch != "I" && ch!= "O" && ch != "U" && ch != "a" && ch!= "e" && ch != "i" && ch!= "o" && ch != "u" ){
            cout << ch << '\n';
            cin>>ch;
            count ++ ;
        }
```